# Blinker/Caret of keyboard was disabled when I created/edited custom combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

First and foremost, I apologize for my grammatical errors; my first language is Persian (Iran).

I edited style , template and toggleButton of ComboBox.following link is my ComboBox photo which is edited (edited style , template and toggleButton)
https://pasteboard.co/JKpa1CL.jpg

Before editing ComboBox , keyboard blinker was enable(keyboard cursor was blinking)
After editing it , blinker remained constant ( and i don't want this ) i want that blinker blinking
This is my codes

```
    <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

    <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

    <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

    <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

    <!--Border colors-->
    <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

    <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

    <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

    <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

    <!--Control-specific resources.-->
    <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

    <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF7381F9" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#600000FF" Offset="0.4" />
                <GradientStop Color="#600000FF" Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="1" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="9" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#e9f1cc" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#cbd3ae" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#858d68" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="DarkGray"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="9,0,0,9" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 3 3 L 6 0 Z" >
                <Path.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF444444"/>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                     Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     Focusable="false"
                     ClickMode="Press"
                     IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                             IsHitTestVisible="False"
                             Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                             ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                             ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                             Margin="3,3,23,3"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                    Style="{x:Null}"
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                    Focusable="True"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Visibility="Hidden"
                    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                  Placement="Bottom"
                  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                  AllowsTransparency="True"
                  Focusable="False"
                  PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                   MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
    TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks

Comment: That is a wall of code, very hard for us to debug. I suggest you start removing bits until it works the way you want, then you will know how it was broken.

Comment: The term you're looking for is *"caret"* (pronounced like "carrot", the vegetable). That's the thing that blinks at the point of text entry. Knowing and using the right term will help you find things about it.

Comment: a quick guess: ```<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </ControlTemplate>``` that seems to eliminate every textediting "character" of your box... so... you just have a focussable Control with no textinput for a blinking caret

Comment: Because I do not know where the blinker code is located (for example in the ToggleButton or ComboBoxTextBox or ... ) so I wrote the whole code

Comment: (madreflection: The term you're looking for is "caret") Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I think the Blinking speed rate  feature should be in <ControlTemplate x: Key = "ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType = "{x: Type TextBox}">.But I do not know exactly where to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray, hooray I found the solution (I found it myself).It  Work 100%

Just Replace this code...

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
 </ControlTemplate>
```

With the following code

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
        </Border>
 </ControlTemplate>
```